# Exclude Header QUERY

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I want to construct a Query that takes data from multiple sheets and lists the contents of them all. All sheets have the same variables and should, therefore, be combined. When typing in 0 as the last argument of the query I always receive an error.

I am using the following formula and have tried to input 0 as well as FALSE as the last argument. Every time I received an error. In addition to this, I tried including `label AI ''` at the end of the statement which worked but I could not seem to also have a blank for AJ. Furthermore, I suspect that the blank spaces will still be shown which I don't want.

```
={QUERY(PRIO!A:AX, "select D, E where B matches 'Negative' order by D");
  QUERY(collated!A:AJ, "select AI, AJ where AG matches 'Negative' order by AJ")}
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure what went wrong because you didn't provide a copy of your sheet but try:

```
={QUERY(PRIO!A1:AX,     "select D, E   where B  matches 'Negative' order by D",  1);
  QUERY(collated!A2:AJ, "select AI, AJ where AG matches 'Negative' order by AJ", 0)}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Together with a colleague we managed to find the problem. The second query gave an empty result with the given sheet (was meant to be added if something should also be filled in on the second sheet). This led to an error when excluding the header. We solved it using IFERROR([QUERYFORMULA],{"",""} for each query individually